# PhantomJS throws error in vue

Tags: javascript, webpack, phantomjs, vue.js

I'm using the webpack template to build a vuejs application. 
The problem is that when I try to run the unit tests (for now just the default one...) PhantomJS throws this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'val.toLowerCase()')
  at webpack:///~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:89:0 <- index.js:13783
```

The error refers to the Vue library so there must be something wrong with the code of the application. 
A little bit of context: I'm creating a showcase of vue component, so I configured webpack to skip a lot of file/folder in the production built because they are simply showcase of components, while I want just the core components in my prod build.

So the structure folder is the following:

```
src
|----components
|----main.js
|----assets.js
|----App.vue
|----core
     |----coreComponents
     |----mainProdBuilder.js
     |----coreAssets.js
```

If I import all the component and if I bundle everything with "main.js" as entry point I can run the tests without any problem but, as soon as I try to use the mainProdBuilder script to bundle the production file I get the error. Here's the script:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import MyTable from "./Table/Table";
import FormatNumber from "./numberFormatting";
import TotalValue from "./TotalValue";
import MyTitle from "./Title/Title";
import TestTitle from "./Title/TestTitle";
import BarChart from "./Charts/BarChart";
import Histogram from "./Charts/Histogram";

Vue.component(MyTable,
    MyTitle,
    TestTitle,
    BarChart,
    TotalValue,
    Histogram,
 );
```

Note that if I comment all the vue component leaving only one component at a time it works. So for example this works:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import MyTable from "./Table/Table";

Vue.component(
    MyTable,
 );
```

And also this works:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import Histogram from "./Charts/Histogram";

Vue.component(
    Histogram,
 );
```

But this throws the error:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import MyTable from "./Table/Table";
import Histogram from "./Charts/Histogram";

Vue.component(
    MyTable,
    Histogram
 );
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue.component()` takes an `id` (i.e. the name of the component) and an `object definition`, you can't register all your global components together (although you can do it for local components), you need to register them separately:

```
import MyTable from "./Table/Table";
import FormatNumber from "./numberFormatting";
//etc...    

Vue.component('my-table', MyTable);
Vue.component('format-number', FormatNumber);
//etc...
```

If you try to register them using one `Vue.component` you get the error you are receiving, which you can see in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6thadjw6/)